# Is it possible to use more than 1 VertexArrayObject in a draw call?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

The subject line says it all really, I just assumed that you could use more than 1, but I can't get it to work with more than one in OpenGL ES 2.0.  I thought that maybe for fine-grained sharing over multiple draw calls, using more than 1 VertexArrayObject would be useful, but I can't think of a particular use case right now.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there can not be more that one VAO bound at the time. That is the purpose of VAO - to simplify binding of vertex attributes just with the one call. If you want more control on individual attribute binding then don't use VAO, just bind the vertex attributes individually.